# Combine two image matrixes and distortion coefficients into one

Tags: python, opencv, math, ros, camera-calibration

So I have been making a program that undistorts an image live and want to cut down the latency between receiving the raw image. The lens is extremely wide and distorted so to do this I have had to calibrate it once using ros_camera_calibration and then once again from that calibrated to get a fully linear image.

These are the two sets camera matrix and distortion coefficients:

```
mtx1 = np.array([[1147.966274, 0.000000, 1274.648950], [0.000000, 1128.032668, 1040.645039], [0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]], dtype=np.float32)
dist1 = np.float32([-0.213467, 0.025685, -0.000622, 0.000044, 0.000000])

mtx2 = np.array([[920.402054, 0.000000, 1259.084897], [0.000000, 922.200175,1035.344627], [0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]], dtype=np.float32)
dist2 = np.float32([-0.109738, 0.015397, -0.006008, 0.001491, 0.000000])
```

and to undistort:

```
dst = cv.undistort(img, mtx1, dist1)
dst = cv.undistort(dst, mtx2, dist2)
```

How can i get these into one full camera matrix and distortion coefficients so I can use one cv.undistort? Thank you in advance

Comment: how much trouble are you willing to go to? this is not trivial. -- wouldn't it be easier to do one complete calibration on the source picture, rather than "calibrating" on an already manipulated image?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The ROS camera calibration isn't that effective. I tried collecting data where it was in the corners, close up, far away etc. but still was a little distorted afterwards so had to go though another time. I am exploring using opencv camera calibrating stuff now also

Comment: What really needed is a mapping table (positions in the input image corresponding to all pixels in the output image) to transform the image, so In principle, it is possible to create one mapping table. (consider to use `remap` instead of `undistort`)

Comment: Of cause it seems nonsense way (in particular, when you have to implement such mapping table calculation by yourself). I believe the "Only one complete calibration" already said by other is best way.